# Selenium with Ruby - getting an error SeleniumRubyWindowsTest.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load

Tags: selenium

SeleniumRubyWindowsTest.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- selenium (Loa
dError)
        from SeleniumRubyWindowsTest.rb:1

I followed the steps from this blog - http://testnerdy.blogspot.ca/2009/10/installing-ruby-and-selenium-on-windows.html

This blog is a little dated, so I am assuming it has to do with that. Anyone have any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Code as requested (this is copy/pasted from http://testnerdy.blogspot.ca/2009/10/running-selenium-tests-written-in-ruby.html)

```
require "selenium"
require "test/unit"

class SeleniumRubyWindowsTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @verification_errors = []
    if $selenium
      @selenium = $selenium
    else
      @selenium = Selenium::SeleniumDriver.new("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://www.yahoo.com/", 10000);
      @selenium.start
    end
    @selenium.set_context("SeleniumRubyWindowsTest")
  end

  def teardown
    @selenium.stop unless $selenium
    assert_equal [], @verification_errors
  end

  def test_SeleniumRubyWindowsTest
    @selenium.open "/"
    assert_equal "Yahoo!", @selenium.get_title
    @selenium.type "p_13838465-p", "Selenium RC"
    @selenium.click "search-submit"
    @selenium.wait_for_page_to_load "30000"
    assert_equal "Selenium RC - Yahoo! Search Results", @selenium.get_title
  end
end
```

Comment: what file are you referencing at line 1 ? Is it there ? Can you include your code ?

Comment: what happens if you open up irb and type "require 'selenium' " ?

Comment: irb(main):001:0> require "selenium"
LoadError: cannot load such file -- selenium
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from (irb):1
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'                                                                       does this mean I have a bad install?

Comment: seems so - what happens if you do 'gem uninstall Selenium' ?

Comment: if that works, do 'gem install Selenium'

Comment: That worked! Do you want to put this as an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: Good to hear it worked, answer added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems my suggestion of doing a gem uninstall and then an install worked